# Stop translating M- commands to lower case?

Tags: key-bindings, key-translation-map

In order to for me to be able to use meta + shift + v as a keybinding, I have to tell emacs to pass `(kbd "M-V")` to `global-set-key` - if I try and use `(kbd "M-S-v")` then this ignored, and when I do `describe-key` for `"M-S-v"` it says `M-v (translated from M-V)` - why is it doing this translation when I've set a keybinding for `M-S-v` and not `M-V`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: See the section 'Modifier Keys' of the Emacs manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html. It, implicitly, mentions that there is no `S` for `Shift`, but instead the 'shifted' characters are typed directly (i.e. `A` instead of `S-a` and `*` instead of `S-8` etc.)